# powershell: Extract data before numeric value from csv file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a strange and bit complicated issue with csv file. CSV file contain 10K+ records. It contains a list of the application version.

> Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf09 
>   Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf11
>   Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf12 
>   Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf14 
>   Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf15 
>   Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf16  Canon MF Toolbox
>   4.9.1.1.mf17  Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf18

I need to get the data before numeric value. So, my output would contain Canon MF Toolbox.

This is just an example there is much software. I can open and read the csv from PowerShell but I am not sure how to get the result which I am looking for.

```
Import-Csv c:\scripts\software.csv |`
    ForEach-Object {
        $Name += $_.Name
       write-host $name;
    }
```

Any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a regex that excludes numbers to your ForEach-Object iterator.

```
$Name = "Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf09 Canon MF Toolbox 4.9.1.1.mf11"

[regex]::Match($Name, "[A-Za-z_\s]*").captures.groups[0].value
```

Returns

> Canon MF Toolbox

If you need to modify the regex as you discover new patterns in your data I recommend [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: You are genius. I thought it is not possible and you prove me wrong. Thanks a lot. I will test and will accept the answer.